# Why won't the items in this table stay in line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Just having the code and running it in jsfiddle it works totally fine. Even here, it seems like it works mostly the way that it should. However, when I put it into my shopify page, the whole thing breaks. It won't select the correct results based on input and it doesn't align properly. On the old theme, it works totally fine and there's no code that directly references anything to do with the theme, so I'm a little lost.

I didn't write this code, except to add the css in an attempt to fix the issues. But it seems like anything I change just makes it worse. It's supposed to be that the image is on the left and the table is on the right, and weirdly it works perfectly in the old theme.

[image]

```js
// <![CDATA[
function btnComputeP_Click() {
  var Length;
  var Height;
  var Depth;


  Length = document.getElementById("Length")
  Height = document.getElementById("Height")
  Depth = document.getElementById("Depth")

  var CheckR

  CheckR = document.getElementById("CheckR")


  if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 2 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 8 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 1.5 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 8 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= .01 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 1.1) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href=http://hideitmounts.com/products/copy-of-hideit-uni-xs-adjustable-small-device-wall-mount?variant=21135992897'> Uni-XS | Adjustable Small Device Wall Mount <br /> <img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/Xs_Product3_Front_web_1024x1024.jpg?v=1468013801' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 3 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 9 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 4 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 10 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 1 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 1.75) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-s-adjustable-set-top-box-mount-oembed' style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-S | Adjustable Small Device Wall Mount <br /> <img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/Direct_TV_4K_box_in_small_adjustable_mount_front_2048x2048.jpg?v=1569324620' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 3 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 9 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 4 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 10 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 1.76 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 2.7) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='https://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-sw-adjustable-small-wide-device-wall-mount'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-SW | Adjustable Small Component Wall Mount <br /> <img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/1_Uni_SWB_MAIN_1024x1024.jpg?v=1520269533' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 9.01 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 13.95 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 6 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 14 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 1.25 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 2.65) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/copy-of-hideit-uni-m-adjustable-set-top-box-mount-oembed'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-M | Adjustable AV Equipment Wall Mount<br /> <img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/1_Uni_M_PRODUCT_GRAPHIC_DEVICE_IN_MOUNT_copy_1024x1024.jpg?v=1513207484' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 9.01 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 13.95 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 6 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 14 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 2.66 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 3.65) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-mw-adjustable-set-top-box-mount-oembed'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-MW | Adjustable TV Component Wall Mount <br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/MW_FiOS_Front_web_88d61f53-b86c-4d5a-a8f1-59447ef18477_1024x1024.jpg?v=1477508927' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 9.01 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 13.95 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 6 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 14 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 3.66 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 4.75) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-mxw-adjustable-component-wall-mount-oembed'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-MXW | Adjustable TV Component Wall Mount<br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/MXW_Classic_PS3_Front_web_529470a9-7c7c-4024-ac47-d9045f9f865c_1024x1024.jpg?v=1468007272' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 13.5 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 17.5 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 8.5 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 16 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 1.25 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 2.65) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-ls-adjustable-device-wall-mount-oembed?variant=7366815553'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-LS | Adjustable Device Wall Mount <br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/LS_Dish_Front_web_1024x1024.jpg?v=1476900970' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 13.5 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 17.5 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 8.5 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 16 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 2.66 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 3.75) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='http://hideitmounts.com/products/hideit-uni-l-adjustable-cable-mount-ombed'style='font-size: 22px;'> Uni-L | Adjustable AV Component Wall Mount<br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/L_DTV_Front_web_1024x1024.jpg?v=1468003115' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 11.1 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 19.1 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 5 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 12 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 1.68 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 2.87) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='https://hideitmounts.com/products/uni-nsm-1u-networking-device-mount'> HIDEit Uni-NSM | Adjustable 1RU Networking Device Mount <br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/Uni-NSM_web_1024x1024.jpg?v=1499362212' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 13.5 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 17.5 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 8.5 && Length.valueAsNumber <= 16 && Depth.valueAsNumber >= 3.75 && Depth.valueAsNumber <= 7) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "<a href='https://hideitmounts.com/products/uni-lxw-tcomputer-mount?variant=7970391162931'> HIDEit Uni-LXW | Adjustable Large Extra-Wide Mount <br /><img width= '25%' height= '25%' src='https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/products/1_LXW_Main_web_1024x1024.jpg?v=1525984457' /></a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber < 2 || Length.valueAsNumber < 1 || Depth.valueAsNumber < 0) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "Your device may be outside of our standard size ranges. Please double check your measurements and <a 'style='font-size: 22px;' href='http://hideitmounts.com/pages/contact-us'>Contact Us</a>"
  } else if (Height.valueAsNumber >= 2 && Height.valueAsNumber <= 8 && Length.valueAsNumber >= 1 && Length.valueAsNumber > 4) {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "Your device may be outside of our standard size ranges. Please double check your measurements and <a 'style='font-size: 22px;' href='http://hideitmounts.com/pages/contact-us'>Contact Us</a>"
  } else {
    CheckR.innerHTML = "Your device may be outside of our standard size ranges. Please double check your measurements and <a 'style='font-size: 22px;' href='http://hideitmounts.com/pages/contact-us'>Contact Us</a>"
  }
}
// ]]>
```

```css
.hideittest {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.eight-columns-alpha {
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.eight-columns-omega {
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="eight columns alpha"><meta charset="utf-8" /><img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0168/7440/files/HIDEit-Dimension-Cheat-Sheet_large.png?3741851581952028760" /></div>
<div class="eight-columns-omega">
<table style="width: 434px; background-color: #222222;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 172px; height: 22px;"><center>Height (Largest)</center></td>
<td style="width: 252px; height: 22px;"><input id="Height" type="number" step=".01" style="width: 70px;" /> inches</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 172px; height: 22px; vertical-align: middle;"><center>Length (Medium)</center></td>
<td style="width: 252px; height: 22px;"><input id="Length" type="number" step=".01" style="width: 70px;" /> inches</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 172px; height: 22px; vertical-align: middle;"><center>Depth (Smallest)</center></td>
<td style="width: 252px; height: 22px;"><input id="Depth" type="number" step=".01" style="width: 70px;" display="flex" /> inches</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align: center;"><meta charset="utf-8" /><strong></strong><br /><a href="#CheckR"><input id="btnComputeP" class="action-button submit-button" type="button" value="FINDit" onclick="btnComputeP_Click()" /></a>  <br /><br /> <meta charset="utf-8" />
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: white;"><strong><label id="CheckR">Result Here</label></strong></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `// <![CDATA[` hasn't been needed for decades.

Comment: @Barmar I had never seen that before, so I didn't know what to do with it. It's commented though, so it shouldn't affect anything anyway, right?

Comment: Right. It was used years ago because some browsers didn't know that they had to parse the contents of `<script>` tags specially.

Comment: Are you sure that the table isn't inheriting CSS properties from ancestor elements on the page? The cause must be something like that if it works fine in isolation.

Comment: @sbgib I'll try adding some '!important' tags and see if that helps. I assumed that by having unique classes for the page that it would bypass any other code like that.

Comment: @sbgib I decided just put everything into flex containers. It doesn't make the word "inches" line up with the input box, but at least it's laid out correctly now.

Comment: @Barmar As it turns out, Shopify automatically adds the // <![CDATA[ tag to any script that I put in. I've tried deleting it multiple times and it keeps coming back.